# Rails subrouting question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hiya everyone!
I need to put off some subroutes in a specific part of an application.
The subroutes shouldbe something like this

```
map.connect ':wildcard/:controller/:id/:action' , :controller => 'my_fancy_controller'
```

problem is , it's not working. putting anything behind :controller will not help.

Environment is rails 2.3.10, not 3 :-).

Someone has some suggestion?

Comment: what does `rake routes` say about it?

Comment: This does not look very RESTful :(

Comment: i know that this doesn't look very RESTful, but i have a spec sheet under my eyes who say "do it!"

Comment: solved! apparently the solution was much more simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer was very very simple.

```
map.connect 'my_fancy_controller/:wildcard/sub_controller/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_fancy_controller/sub_controller'
```

In this way i can use my_fancy_controller and sub_controller as static text in the url, declaring them in the :controller field.

Is not rest, but it's the way my job have to be done, so i'm sorry for you purists!